# Android Refresh gallery force closes app

Tags: java, android, move

I have an issue refreshing the gallery on the android device.
Android device being used to debug with is a Galaxy Note 3 with NO sd card.

After deleting a file, a refresh has to be done on the entire gallery otherwise the image is still visible in the gallery of the phone even though it has been deleted (because there isn't a better way to do this for the deletion of a file to my knowledge)

But when I do the refresh the app force closes. I would guess that it has something to do with the phone not having a SD card to mount/unmount.

Is there a way to refresh the gallery besides this piece of code? Or do you know why the application would force close after the delete?

```
 sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

I've also tried playing with that code as to change it to something like this, but still the error persists.

```
     String selectedFile = getRealPathFromURI(selectedURI);
     me.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse(selectedFile)));

    private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
                return contentURI.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            return cursor.getString(idx);
        }
    }
```

Also just for a last resort I tried this. The app didn't crash, but didn't scan the file / or fix the problem either.

```
 sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

EDIT: I have added the permissions in the Manifest only for

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found how to fix this.

You have to execute this on the main thread. There might be a way around this and if some one would add to this then it would be great.

So Fix : This has to be executed in your main activity for some reason.